# Backend failed to start up Error: The migration directory is corrupt, the following files are missing:

Tags: database, migration, knex.js

So, during a deployment we faced this issue:

Backend failed to start up Error: The migration directory is corrupt, the following files are missing: ...

There were three pluggins listed. Our "workaround" was to remove the three pluggin name entries in the knex_migrations table.

Went through the backstage docs on pluggins and noted a metion of knex.js.  I would like to know what is the knex_migrations table for?  Can we nuke it and backstage will automagically recreate it? How is knex used in w.r.t to the pluggin architecture in Backstage ?  Can we programmatically reset this table upon deploy?

..thanks..
rgds,
Miguel

Our "workaround" was to remove the three pluggin name entries in the knex_migrations table.

Comment: Wow!  I would never have got this...  I just had to delete the one record (matching my error message) from the `backstage_plugin_auth` database, table `knex_migrations`.  Now if only I had any idea what caused it...